# In an SVG, can you reuse a common linearGradient but change the colors from CSS?

Tags: html, css, svg

In an SVG, can you reuse a common linearGradient but change the colors from CSS?

I have the following HTML:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 240 240" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="240" height="240">
  <defs>
      <linearGradient id="sharedGradient" class="grad" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="var(--color-top)" />
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="var(--color-bot)" />
      </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <g transform="translate(0, 0)">
    <rect class="node"        width="100" height="100" x="0" y="0"></rect>  
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(120, 0)">
    <rect class="node green"  width="100" height="100" x="0" y="0"></rect>
  </g>
</svg>
```

...and the following CSS:

```
.node {
  fill: url(#sharedGradient) #00FF00;
}

#sharedGradient {
  --color-top: #f12c06;
  --color-bot: #faed34;
}

.green #sharedGradient   {
  --color-top: #00ff00;
  --color-bot: #00dd00;
}
```

But I can't find a way to alter the color stops of the gradient without duplicating the whole  tag in the SVG.

Comment: No you can't do it that way. Separate colours means separate gradients. You might be able to use currentColour but even if you did, that would only allow you to customise a single colour.

Comment: Not sure if that would really help, but I think that theoretically, **in this case** since both shape are actually the same, you could have had a symbol that would contain both the `<rect>` and the `<linearGradient>` and pass the CSS variables through a `<use>`. This actually does work in Firefox, but not in Chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/21a8o694/

Answer (score 1):

Like @Kaiido mentioned, the linearGradient just needs to be in the svg part that is being reused via `<use href="..." />`, then in Firefox that can be styled with css-variables. In chrome only the default values will be shown.

```css
#svg1 {
 stroke: url(#gradient);
}

#svg2 {
 stroke: url(#gradient);
 --color-top: blue;
 --color-bot: red;
}

#svg3 {
 stroke: url(#cantBeStyled); // but reused
 --color-top: violet;
 --color-bot: indigo;
}
```

```html
<html>
<div>
 <svg id="svg1">
  <defs>
   <linearGradient id="cantBeStyled" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="var(--color-top, green)" />
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="var(--color-bot, yellow)" />
   </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <g id="toReuse">
   <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="var(--color-top, green)" />
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="var(--color-bot, yellow)" />
   </linearGradient>
   <rect width="100" height="100" x="0" y="0" stroke-width="20"></rect>
  </g>
 </svg>
</div>
<div>CSS-variables work in Firefox, in chrome all gradients are green-yellow as defined as defaults in the svg</div>
<div>
  can be styled via css variables
 <svg id="svg2">
  <use href="#toReuse"></use>
 </svg>
</div><br /><br/><br/>
<div>
 can't be styled
 <svg id="svg3">
  <use href="#toReuse"></use>
 </svg>
</div>
</html>
```